# Why does my 'averageScore' come out as 0?

Tags: c#, loops

why does my code not calculate an average score when entering "-1" into the console? It comes up at 0. It's a part of a loop exercise, so I'm sure there are faster ways to code this. I want to fix it within my current C# comprehension.

[Here's the task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxI38.png)

```
using System;

namespace Challenge_Loops1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string individualScore = "0";
            int scoreCount = 0;
            int totalScore = 0;
            int individualScoreIntoInt = 0;

            while (individualScore != "-1")
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Last number was {individualScoreIntoInt}");
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter the next score");
                Console.WriteLine($"Current amount of entries: {scoreCount}");
                Console.WriteLine("Enter '-1' when you're ready to calculaate the average");

                individualScore = Console.ReadLine();

                if (individualScore.Equals("-1"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------");
                    double averageScore = (double)totalScore / (double)scoreCount;
                    Console.WriteLine($"The average total score is {averageScore}");
                    
                    if(int.TryParse(individualScore, out individualScoreIntoInt) && individualScoreIntoInt > 0 && individualScoreIntoInt < 21)
                    {
                        totalScore += individualScoreIntoInt;
                        //longer way: totalScore = individualScoreIntoInt + totalScore;
                    }
                    else if(individualScoreIntoInt < 0 || individualScoreIntoInt < 20)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Enter a score > 0 and < 21");
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Please only enter numbers");
                    }
                
                }

                scoreCount++; // adding the individualscore entered to the count. writing it here so that it's only
                //added to the count if it meets the requirements

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Reformat your code. Your indentation does not represent the structure of your program. Then step through it while it's executing.

Comment: Your `else if` should be `individualScoreIntoInt < 1 || individualScoreIntoInt > 20`

Comment: Maybe so, but none of that happens until the user enters "-1". The exit condition block doesn't close until just before `scoreCount` is incremented.

Comment: @madreflection Yeah, the fact that all the `int` parsing is inside the first `if` is the problem.

Comment: @madreflection is right, initial if statements should be fixed. She didn't actually perform any operations before inserting "-1", it should be if(-1) .... elseif(>0 && <21)..elseif(<0!!>21) else().. rather than if(if(...)elseif(...)else(...))

Comment: Hi @madreflection, what do you mean by "stepping through it while it's executing"?

Comment: `if (individualScore.Equals("-1"))`  let that sink in.  We can agree that individual score equals -1, right? Now consider what happens when you do `int.TryParse(individualScore, out individualScoreIntoInt)`  Many of your other logical expressions are wrong.

Comment: @Magda: I'm talking about using the debugger to run each statement one at a time.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2022

Comment: Rethink order of operations :)

Comment: thanks for quick replies madreflection juharr Krzysiek Wyck :)

Answer (score 1):

Order of operations was incorrect:
1st validate if it's -1 or not,
2nd parse value and if it's possible perform below operations, if not drop error.
This was logic issue, rather than code itself.
You had added iteration despite exceptions, you didn't include possibility of 21 etc.

```
namespace Challenge_Loops1
    {
        internal class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                string individualScore = "0";
                int scoreCount = 0;
                int totalScore = 0;
                int individualScoreIntoInt = 0;
    
                while (individualScore != "-1")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Last number was {individualScoreIntoInt}");
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the next score");
                    Console.WriteLine($"Current amount of entries: {scoreCount}");
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter '-1' when you're ready to calculaate the average");
    
                    individualScore = Console.ReadLine();
    
                    if (individualScore.Equals("-1"))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------");
                        double averageScore = (double)totalScore / (double)scoreCount;
                        Console.WriteLine($"The average total score is {averageScore}");
                    }
                    else if (int.TryParse(individualScore, out individualScoreIntoInt))
                    {
                        if(individualScoreIntoInt > 0 && individualScoreIntoInt <= 21)
                        {
                            totalScore += individualScoreIntoInt;
                            scoreCount++;
                        }
//as mentioned in comment else here would also work, it's unnecessary to add any other validation.
                        else if (individualScoreIntoInt < 0 || individualScoreIntoInt > 21)
                        { 
                            Console.WriteLine("Enter a score > 0 and < 21");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Please only enter numbers");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would even recommend to first tryParse the value and completely base decisions on the integer value.

Comment: A lot more could be changed, i wanted to point out issues in exact code :)

Comment: `else if (individualScoreIntoInt < 0 || individualScoreIntoInt > 21)` this check is superfluent. You already established this by the first check resulting in `false`.

Comment: Ok, thats true, unnecessary one. But let's leave it with comment for OP.

Comment: thank you Krzysiek! It helped me to understand what goes where in this particular structure :)